# Pra que serve a propriedade "pointer-events"?

Tags: css3

Estava pesquisando uma maneira de estilizar a setinha do `<select />` e me deparei com uma solução que usava uma `<label>` com o valor `pointer-events: none`.

Eu gostaria de saber para que serve esse `pointer-events` com o valor `none`, e quais são as outras opções que podem ser usadas nessa propriedade?

Comment: [Como impedir um click sobre um link/âncora ou elemento com evento amarrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2352/129)

Comment: @Sergio e as outras combinações? eu perguntei *outras opções que podem ser usadas nessa propriedade*

Comment: Uma abordagem que julgo ser interessante nesse caso é o uso desta propriedade junto com SVG.

Comment: Galera, acho interessante deixar aberta, já que também abrange [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pointer-events` controla como aquele elemento responderá aos eventos do mouse do usuário. São poucas opções:

- `none` - cancelará todo o evento de mouse
- `auto` - restaura os eventos do mouse para o normal. Pode ser útil para elementos filho que estão dentro de elementos com o `pointer-events: none`
- `inherit` - herda do elemento pai

```js
$('div').click(function () {
  alert('teste');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.vovo{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.pai{
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.filho{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vovo">
  <div class="pai">
    <div class="filho">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`pointer-events: none;` previne que qualquer ação do ponteiro do mouse (*pointer*) sobre o elemento especificado (como clicar, arrastar, hover etc..). O valor natural de `pointer-events` é `auto`.

Valor `inherit`: não justifica-se muito seu uso. Quando você especifica `pointer-events: none;` (ou `auto`) a um elemento, todos os *elementos-filhos* já herdam tal valor.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div style="pointer-events: none;">

   <!-- não fez sentido usar inherit no elemento abaixo,
   já que ele herda automaticamente o none da div-pai -->

   <a href="" style="pointer-events: inherit;">Link</a>
   <br />
   <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

Existem outros valores para `pointer-events`, mas só aplicam-se a SVG (*gráficos vetoriais escaláveis*):

- `visiblePainted`
- `visibleFill`
- `visibleStroke`
- `visible`
- `painted`
- `fill`
- `stroke`
- `all`

Para detalhes dessas especificações, você pode consultar uma documentação no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).